# Windows: Batch script to map a remote computer's share folder using a local login/password on THAT computer

Tags: windows, batch, network-shares, network-drive, net-use

I have a non domain computer I am running a shared network folder from, and that I connect with using an account that's locally on that computer.

Doing it manually via the Map A Network Drive in windows works fine:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjjfM.png

However I want to create/use a batch script to do this since I run this off of new computers to run installs. The format I've seen online I've been trying to use is:

```shell
net use z: \\p2host\fs /USER:\\p2host\fs Fileshare1 /PERSISTENT:NO
```

This doesn't work. If I try to use "localhost\fs" or ".\fs" I think it's trying to find/use the creds on the local computer I'm configuring which also doesn't have the information.

How can I input the local user information from the shared folder computer into the batch script to work?

Comment: the syntax for `/USER:` is  `/USER:p2host\username password` so it would be `net use z: \\p2host\fs /USER:p2host\username password /PERSISTENT:NO`  . It looks like you are setting the user to the fileshare path by accident.